# SQLite error SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED for exFAT drive

Tags: c++, macos, sqlite, fat

I have OS X and external hard drive with exFAT and with SQLite database there.

When I try to write in database, I get SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED error, but I can access to make operation writing, creating file/folders in drive.

Why?

Comment: Is there a *rollback journal* file (`-journal`) associated with the database?

Comment: It has to be created normally.
I tried to use SQLITE_TEMP_STORE with 1 and 2 value, but the problem persists